# Plugin for VS 2008 - With Structural Highlighting - Support Syntax Delphi Prism

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, plugins, delphi-prism, oxygene

Anybody know any plugin for Visual Studio 2008 that has the ability to "Structural Highlighting" and Syntax support  for [Delphi-Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism).

Currently use [Castalia](http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/structural_highlighting.html) and [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en), but just work on Rad Studio.

I've also used [Codekana](http://www.codekana.com/), but does not support the syntax of Delphi Prism.

[image]

Bye.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to tag delphi prism related questions as delphi.

Comment: Francisco included the tag delphi intentionally because it is more possible for a delphi developer knows a plugin for delphi prism.

Comment: Have you contacted the guys at Codekana to ask if they would add support for Prism?

Comment: Bruce that is a good option, but for now I would like to find some existing plugin.

Comment: For that matter, I wonder if DevExpress will support Prism any time soon?

Comment: Per Julian Bucknall of DevExpress they are planning to support Delphi Prism with their IDE tools: http://www.delphi.org/2008/11/15-julian-bucknall-on-devexpress/

Comment: Jon the author & vendor of Codekana here. I'll definitely try to add support for other languages in the future, including Delphi-Prism. Shouldn't be too hard (but my to-do list is huge!).

Answer (score 1):

Given the comments, the answer probably is 'there is not yet structural syntax highlighting for Delphi Prism' :-)

You might also want to contact the people at DevExpress, or hook the people at [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) up with the people at [RemObjects](http://www.remobjects.com/).

RemObjects is the company that developed the whole [Delphi Prism](http://www.codegear.com/delphi/prism) language and Visual Studio IDE integration: that product is called [Oxygene](http://www.remobjects.com/oxygene.aspx).

CodeRush does structural syntax highlighting (and [much more](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/06/25/coderush-xpress-for-c-and-visual-basic-2008.aspx), even in their free edition). It used to be available for Delphi, but is now Visual Studio only, and works for the C# and VB.NET personalities.
[Mark Miller](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/default.aspx) is the guy behind CodeRush (he started it in the Delphi world).

Since CodeRush is based on DxCore, DxCore does C#, VB.NET and ASPX, and DxCore is public, so you could roll your own structural syntax highlighting :-)

[Julian Bucknall](http://www.boyet.com/) (CTO of DevExpress) already [hinted on support for Delphi Prism in their products](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/ctodx/archive/2008/11/19/dxperience-and-delphi-prism.aspx) and [elaborated on that](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/ctodx/archive/2008/12/04/dxperience-and-delphi-prism-part-deux.aspx).

Olaf Monien wrote about [using DxCore to enable Sync Edit for Delphi Prism](http://www.monien.net/blog/index.php/2008/12/enable-sync-editing-in-delphi-prism/).

Personally I have not used [Codekana](http://www.codekana.com/) yet, mainly because I rely on macros and refactoring a lot. At first sight Codekana does not support those, but I'd love to be corrected on that :-)

Comment: Jeroen, Codekana indeed does not have any refactoring support. Care to explain exactly what you mean by macros? Thanks!

Comment: I mistyped: I meant template expansion. You an find out more on the link below. The real strength of CodeRush here, is that the expansion is context sensitive. http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/whatsnewv2.xml

Answer (score 0):

There is no product that provides structural highlighting with syntax support for Delphi Prism under VS.

Excellent question, which highlights an available development niche.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, it's not quite the same, but i use smartoutline in visual studio 2008. It's mainly for collapsing specified regions of code, but it also marks up the structures in the margin. You have to specify the regions yourself, but once done it makes code a lot easier to read